# I want id with any one of the given details

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

Here is my models:

```
enter code here

class Room_Type(models.Model):
    """Django data model Room_Type"""
    ROOM_CATEGORIES={
    ('Elt','Elite'),
    ('Lux','Luxury'),
    ('Sig','Signature')
    }
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="pics")
    roomtype = models.CharField(choices=ROOM_CATEGORIES,max_length=20)
    price = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.roomtype}
```

I want Id with any one of the detail given in model,Help me solve geeks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you create a model id is automatically created in django if you want to access that id you can access like this in your view

```
room_type = Room_Type.objects.get(name='John')
print(room_type.id)
```

Comment: Room_Type matching query does not exist.

Comment: Here it is my views:                                                        def booking(request,room):
    if request.method=='POST':
        roomType=Room_Type.objects.get(roomtype=['type'])
        print(roomType.id)

Comment: Room_Type matching query does not exist. this error occur becouse which type you are looking is not exists in database. try to fech which data is exists in database                                             roomType=Room_Type.objects.get(roomtype=look_for_data_which_exists_in_database)